# Expanding dataframe with specific frequency - Python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following columns (just an excerpt):

```
     START                    END               FREQ     VARIABLE    
'2017-03-26 16:55:00'  '2017-10-28 16:55:00'   1234567      x
'2017-03-26 20:35:00'  '2017-10-28 20:35:00'   1234567      y
'2017-03-26 14:55:00'  '2017-10-28 14:55:00'   ..3.567      y
'2017-03-26 11:15:00'  '2017-10-28 11:15:00'   1234567      y
'2017-03-26 09:30:00'  '2017-06-11 09:30:00'   ......7      x
```

My goal is to create a new dataframe that expands this one by producing daily rows that start on the 'START' date and finish on the 'END' date, according to the 'FREQ' column. In this 'FREQ' column, 1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday. A 'dot' denotes that the row should not be created in that specific day of the week. So,  ..3.5.7 will only correspond to 3 new rows on Wednesday, Friday and Sunday only. The 'VARIABLE' column should always have the same value for each of the created rows.

My major problem is that the new dataframe will have millions of rows, therefore, I was looking for a really efficient solution.

The dataframe written in Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([ 
'2017-03-26 16:55:00','2017-10-28 16:55:00', '1234567', 'x',
'2017-03-26 20:35:00','2017-10-28 20:35:00','1234567','y',
'2017-03-26 14:55:00','2017-10-28 14:55:00','..3.567','y',
'2017-03-26 11:15:00','2017-10-28 11:15:00','1234567','y',
'2017-03-26 09:30:00','2017-06-11 09:30:00','......7','x']).reshape((5, 4)))
df.columns = ['START','END','FREQ','VARIABLE']
```

Comment: `My major problem is that the new dataframe will have millions of rows`. Therefore, can you show us working code [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52146911/edit) that works for a *smaller* dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised answer:

This uses pandas iloc and numpy repeat to make a new dataframe from the original dataframe index, but after determining the repeat indexes based on the date ranges and valid weekdays.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_arr = np.array([ 
    '2017-03-26 16:55:00', '2017-10-28 16:55:00', '1234567', 'x',
    '2017-03-26 20:35:00', '2017-10-28 20:35:00', '1234567', 'y',
    '2017-03-26 14:55:00', '2017-10-28 14:55:00', '..3.567', 'y',
    '2017-03-26 11:15:00', '2017-10-28 11:15:00', '1234567', 'y',
    '2017-03-26 09:30:00', '2017-06-11 09:30:00', '......7',' x'])

df = pd.DataFrame(df_arr.reshape(5, 4),
                  columns=['START', 'END', 'FREQ', 'VARIABLE'])

def get_weekdays_dates_repeats(start, end, valid_weekday_nums):
    date_range = pd.date_range(start, end, freq="D", normalize=True)
    all_day_nums = date_range.dayofweek.values + 1
    filtered_idx = np.where(np.isin(all_day_nums, valid_weekday_nums))
    day_nums = all_day_nums[filtered_idx]
    dates = date_range[filtered_idx]
    return day_nums, dates.values.astype('<M8[D]'), day_nums.size

starts = df.START.values
ends = df.END.values
freqs = df.FREQ.str.replace('.', '').values

repeats = np.zeros(len(df))
weekdays_arr_list = []
dates_arr_list = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    valid_day_nums = [int(s) for s in list(freqs[i])]
    days, dates, repeat = \
        get_weekdays_dates_repeats(starts[i], ends[i], valid_day_nums)
    weekdays_arr_list.append(days)
    dates_arr_list.append(dates)
    repeats[i] = repeat

weekday_col = np.concatenate(weekdays_arr_list)
dates_col = np.concatenate(dates_arr_list)
repeats = repeats.astype(int)

df2 = df.iloc[np.repeat(df.index.values, repeats)].reset_index(drop=True)

df2['day_num'] = weekday_col
df2['date'] = dates_col
```

df2.head()

```
                  START        END          FREQ    VARIABLE    day_num date
0   2017-03-26 16:55:00 2017-10-28 16:55:00 1234567 x   7   2017-03-26
1   2017-03-26 16:55:00 2017-10-28 16:55:00 1234567 x   1   2017-03-27
2   2017-03-26 16:55:00 2017-10-28 16:55:00 1234567 x   2   2017-03-28
3   2017-03-26 16:55:00 2017-10-28 16:55:00 1234567 x   3   2017-03-29
4   2017-03-26 16:55:00 2017-10-28 16:55:00 1234567 x   4   2017-03-30
```

df2.tail()

```
                  START                END  FREQ    VARIABLE    day_num date
782 2017-03-26 09:30:00 2017-06-11 09:30:00 ......7 x   7   2017-05-14
783 2017-03-26 09:30:00 2017-06-11 09:30:00 ......7 x   7   2017-05-21
784 2017-03-26 09:30:00 2017-06-11 09:30:00 ......7 x   7   2017-05-28
785 2017-03-26 09:30:00 2017-06-11 09:30:00 ......7 x   7   2017-06-04
786 2017-03-26 09:30:00 2017-06-11 09:30:00 ......7 x   7   2017-06-11
```

Comment: This solution does not seem to be correct. The dataframe only has 26 rows. It should have 787 rows. The goal is not to create a "day" column, but to repeat each row from start to end, according with the frequency mentioned.

Comment: The "day" column is only included as a validator, not the end goal.  I thought you only wanted  a new row for each "FREQ" indicator ("So, ..3.5.7 will only correspond to 3 new rows on Wednesday, Friday and Sunday only").  Now I see you want to use the time values to create days within each time range and exclude days indicated with a dot in the FREQ column.  Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. It is precisely that. The solution already posted here does exactly what I am looking for. However, unfortunately, it is a bit slow. Are you aware of any possibility to increase the performance of the previous solution?

Comment: Maybe.  I will think about it more.

Comment: @MiguelLambelho I updated my answer to only concat the DataFrames once... should give a slight performance boost

Comment: @MiguelLambelho I revised my answer and am curious to know how fast it is with your data.  I don't like the loop with the continual call to pd.date_range but don't have any more time to look at this now.  The "day_num" and "date" columns are there just for checking the validity of the results.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It is extremely fast when compared to the DataFrame.iterrows(). Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one potential way to achieve this using **`DataFrame.iterrows()`**:

```
chunks = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    freq = [int(i)-1 for i in str(row[2]).replace('.', '')]
    dateidx = [d for d in pd.date_range(row[0], row[1], freq='D') if d.weekday() in freq]
    chunks.append(pd.DataFrame({'date': dateidx}).assign(variable=row[3]))
df_expanded = pd.concat(chunks, ignore_index=True)
```